# How to read ctx.request.body in koa 2 (without body-parser)?

Tags: javascript, http-post, koa2

I want to read `ctx.request.body` from a post without body-parser middleware.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();
app.use(router.routes());

router.post('/publish', async (ctx, next) => {
  let msg = JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body);
  console.log(msg); //undefined
  console.log(ctx.request.body); //undefined
  console.log(ctx.req.body);  //undefined
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Using `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"val"}' 'http://localhost:8080/publish'` I get 3 undefined.

How do I solve this problem? I know that koa can't parse `req.body`, but why doesn't `JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body)` work?

Comment: Why don't you want to use body-parser?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body)` does not work, because it only gets set if you use one of the available body parsers. So if you *do not want* to use body-parser (or any other body-parser middleware), you have to parse the body from `req.body` by yourself.

But honestly, why would you not want to use one of the existing solutions for your problem?